# @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment: Unsafe assignment of an `any` value

Tags: node.js, typescript, vue.js

I am using TypeScript in my client , when i run my application , there are two errors show as follow :

```
@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment: Unsafe assignment of an `any` value.

@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access: Unsafe member access .value on an `any` value.
```

Here is my code :

```
const userInfo = ref({} as UserInfo) // first error

$f.axios
    .get<UserInfo>('/comm/auth/get-my-info')
    .then((result) => {
      userInfo.value = result.data // second error
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      //....
    })
```

UserInfo in .ts:

```
export interface UserInfo {
  userName: string
  realName: string
  password: string | null
  email: string | null
  mobilePhone: string | null
  appToken: string | null
  internalTags: string | null
  enabledState: boolean
  isApiUser: boolean
  createDt: Date
  createP: string
  createPn: string | null
  updateDt: Date
  updateP: string
  updatePn: string | null
  firstLogin: true
  passwordExpiresDt: Date | null
  rolesString: string | null
  userRoleIds: number[] | null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment: Unsafe assignment of an `any` value.

This means that the properties in `response.data` might not match the ones of the interface `UserInfo`.

We can get rid of this `ESLint warning` by adding like **:**

```
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment
```

> @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access: Unsafe member access .value on an `any` value.

As per the above error, You don't have any `value` property in your `UserInfo` interface. Hence, it is expecting `value` property should be there in the interface. Issue will get resolve by adding it in the `UserInfo`.

Comment: Thanks, add this note, the first error can be solved , but the second error still exist.

Comment: Second error coming as you dont have any `value` property in your `UserInfo` interface. Hence, it is expecting `value` property should be there in the interface. Issue will get resolve by defining it.